# Stack Exchange All Site page directing to the wrong users

Tags: bug, status-completed, users, stackexchange.com

On this page:
https://stackexchange.com/sites

When I click on the site, and on a user avatar, it takes me to a different user profile. It appears to be doing this for all of the sites and profiles, but isn't random (i.e. it's the same "wrong" profile every time).

Answer (score 8):

It looks like it's taking the user's site id (for example, for a random user I picked, [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) on SuperUser, that'd be 337631) and then plugging that in as the SE Network ID (in David's case, that'll take you to https://stackexchange.com/users/337631, which is the profile of user666010).

So it's just <strike>grabbing the incorrect ID on the account</strike> sticking the ID into the wrong link.

Comment: Strictly speaking... it's actually just linking to the wrong site in the first place. :) The links were supposed to go to the Q&A sites, not stackexchange.com.

Comment: I had a 50/50 on guessing your intent @Adam :P